# How to horizontally move polygon on top of the TIN or DEM?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, overlapping-features, arcscene, drape

I am wondering if there is any effective method to shifting the polygon (to right hand side) to above the ridge in ArcScene?

It shifts around 60 meters which make my analysis inaccurate. Do you know how to solve this? I also attached the image in order to make you easier understandable what happens.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may try **geo-reference** the polygon,

i think with the small shift you have 1st order polynomial
(using only one point)
would be enough.